# How to evaluate an accumulator without incurring a write?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, counter

I want to perform lightweight validation before writing a dataframe. I have to serialize the dataframe through "foo" before writing it. I am incrementing an accumulator in "foo":

```
acc = sc.accumulator(0)
output = df.map(foo)
if acc.value < THRESHOLD:
 raise ValueError(f"Failed validation: {acc.value} < {THRESHOLD}")
output.write(path)
```

The problem is that `acc.value == 0` because the accumulator is apparently not evaluated until `output.write()`, which I want to avoid because the data failed validation. What's the right design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to validate the count before publishing the data to some output path, simply write the data to an intermediate path. Then evaluate the accumulator counter, and if the count is valid - rename the intermediate path to the real output destination.

```
acc = sc.accumulator(0)
output = df.map(foo)
output.write(tmp_path)
if acc.value < THRESHOLD:
 # fs.delete(tmp_path)
 raise ValueError(f"Failed validation: {acc.value} < {THRESHOLD}")
else fs.rename(tmp_path, path)
```

Comment: Creative thinking: I like it! Renaming would not work because my files are in S3, which does not allow renames, but perhaps I could delete the corrupt files.

Comment: I guess you just need to make sure the second operation (rename, delete, etc.) is atomic